# Determine the orginal build location / path of an exe using .Net Reflector or another tool

Tags: c#, .net-reflector

I have an EXE that is currently deployed on our production server (c# .net 2). I have inherited the task of making some changes to this app and re-deploying.

I didn't write this app and I have been pointed at a few different folders on various network drives with a few different Visual Studio solutions (~10) that were various incantations of this app through time and could be contenders for the Visual Studio project that was used to generate this exe but I don't know which project was used that matches the in production EXE.

**Is there a way using .net Reflector or another tool to determine the original file path the source files lay when they were used to compile the EXE**, I can then work backwards to determine the correct Visual Studio solution and start making changes there.

Thanks

Comment: Wow. Get your projects under source control now!

Comment: This is a situation I've inherited in a contract position, it's out of my control. I therefore must best deal with the situation I'm in. And yes everything I can I am consolidating into source control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like one hell of a situation if you can't get to know what's the origin of what's running in production.

Nonetheless, one possible solution is to have a look at the debug header of the .exe assembly, if it has been compiled with debug symbols, it may contain the original full path of the pdb, giving you a clue of where it has been built. You can get it with the `dumpbin` tool that is part of the windows sdk.

Here's an example of the output:

```
  Debug Directories

        Time Type       Size      RVA  Pointer
    -------- ------ -------- -------- --------
    4A0F2A94 cv           51 0006672C    6492C    Format: RSDS, {77468AA8-8494-46AC-87DF-422721517504}, 8, C:\sources\mcs\class\Mono.Cecil\obj\Debug\Mono.Cecil.pdb
```

Better yet, if you have the pdb handy, you can use a tool like [pdbdump](http://code.google.com/p/pdbdump/) to know which files were used to compile the assembly.

Comment: Awesome, great tip there! dumpbin worked a treat :-) thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use Reflector & one of the file generator plugins at http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins to dump the code into files.  Before making any changes though, make sure you can rebuild.